# Unable to enumerate groups/results while using ALAssetsLibrary in static library

Tags: ios, static-libraries, alassetslibrary

*This question is kind of solved, but one more request remaining at the bottom of this question. And I will choose an answer after all.*

---

I am creating a static library that is using `AssetsLibrary framework`. While I am using it in a project to test whether is work. It return nothing while I call the `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` method of the instance of `AssetsLibrary`.

I have trying -

1. to set breakpoints to see how it running this method. Turns out it did not go into the block that passing to `usingBlock:`, which is `ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock`, and either the `failureBlock:`. So that I got nothing.
2. to add the same enumerating code to the project I mentioned at the beginning to try to calling method of `AssetsLibrary`. it worked perfectly **fine**.
3. to test whether it is block by the main thread, then run it in the main thread. Got the same result as before.

For this issue, I have found an answer of other question that is talking about using media in the static library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331319/1583560, and I am not sure I have run into the same situation, is the media he/she mentions including accessing `AssetsLibrary`, I guess no here.

Hope someone can point some directions of this, thank you :)

---

#### Update

This is the code I used -

```
[[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                                              usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                                  NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                                              } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                                  NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                                              }];
```

Code in the static library is the same as in the test project, the only difference is I make a model class to access `AssetsLibrary` in the static library.

To be clear, here are few changes I have made in the static library -

- Change `Build Product Path` in *Target > Build Settings* to `$(PROJECT_DIR)/../build`
- Moving required header file to Project section in *Target > Build Phases > Copy Headers*
- Set `Skip Install` to `YES` in *Target > Build Settings*

Environment related -

- OS X 10.9.1
- Xcode 5.0.2
- Standard architectures (including 64-bit)  *(both static library and the project)*
- ARC

---

#### More details

Here is my propose to make a assets model for easy accessing in this static library.

- Having a group array to store all the albums, which is `ALAssetsGroup` here, in devices.
- Enumerating *albums* out at the `init` of this model and storing into the group array.
- Enumerating *photos*, which is `ALAssets` result, by the group given while needed.

And this model using singleton pattern.

*BTW*, I have tried to observe the `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` in this static library. It's not working, too. <strike>Are there any potential obstructs at the front of `AssetsLibrary`?</strike>

---

#### Update

I have find out that I enumerate the groups while `init` the model I created. And there are threads make blocks not work. If I trigger the enumerate after the `init` complete, will work perfectly. And I also found the way to know when it is done enumerating (cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309871/1583560) to get the group array which I stored.

***Further***, I still cannot find the document, Apple's, that addressing the threading of block, why it will not been call while `init`, yet. If someone could point out for me, I will appreciate it :).

Comment: Hi, thank you for asking code. I have updated the question and added it at the end of the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about "unable to enumerate assets on devices", because of the async of enumerating `ALAssetsGroup`.

---

### The Async

According to apple's document about `enumerateGroupsWithTypes:usingBlock:failureBlock:` of `ALAssetsLibrary`, this is an async method, will not get full data stored in array after it run.

> This method is **asynchronous**. When groups are enumerated, the user may be asked to confirm the application's access to the data; the method, though, returns immediately. You should perform whatever work you want with the assets in enumerationBlock.

---

### Completion Notification

I do want to know when it is done. so that I have found an answer for knowing when the progress is done, and execute a block (cf. [Create my own completion blocks in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14586750/1583560)). Even though this is not about the notification, but still gave me a hint to work it out.

#### `postNotification:` while it reach the end of the enumeration

```
[_assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos  
                              usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                                  if(group){
                                      // add into the array you are going to use
                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                      // the last one will be nil, 
                                      // it also means the enumeration is done
                                      // post notification then
                                      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kEnumerateGroupCompleteNotification]; 
                                  }
                              }
                            failureBlock:nil]; // leave nil here for make subject out
```

#### `addObserver:selector:name:object:` to add observer for reloading data

*First*, using the empty `NSArray`, which is the retained array we are using at previous step, in the `~DataSource` protocol of `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`.

*Second*, adding an observer to the `UIViewController`, using `@selector` pass to this method to trigger the instance's `reloadData` to get the complete array just enumerating out. And the data will be shown on the view.

```
// In a UIViewController's implementation 

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadTableView:)
                                                 name:kEnumerateGroupCompleteNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)reloadTableView:(NSNotification*) notification {

    // reloadData after receive the notification
    [_tableView reloadData];

}
```

---

### Conclusion

This is the way how I achieve my requirement. I have addressed `ALAssetsGroup` only above, but it will be the same in `ALAssets`'s enumeration.

It is the same way if you want to get `ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification` and reload data.

And a great thank for Ramshad's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152192/1583560), I have accessing `ALAssetsLibrary` as your suggestion in my static library now.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method to your class:

```
+ (ALAssetsLibrary *)defaultAssetsLibrary
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred = 0;
    static ALAssetsLibrary *library = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    });
    return library;
}
```

Then modify your code as

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetsLibrary = [ViewController defaultAssetsLibrary];
[assetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
     {
        if(result)
        {
           NSLog(@"Success");
        }
     }];

 } failureBlock:^(NSError *error)
 {
        NSLog(@"Error loading images %@", error);
 }];
```

Comment: Thank you, and it is a great approach that using singleton for `AssetsLibrary`, but I still got nothing after following your suggestion, I will update more detail of the assets model I made.